# Guardar input en la base de datos

Tags: html, laravel

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un formulario en *Laravel* donde dos campos se llenan con una función en *JS* que crea un código, todo funciona bien pero cuando voy a guardar el formulario estos dos campos no me los inserta en la base de datos

**Blade:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label">Lote No</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text"   name="lote" id="lote" value="lote" disabled >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <input value="cformulario" title="codigo formulario" type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo_formulario" id="cformulario" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function saveform(Request $request) {
    $headform = new headform();

    $headform->maquina = $request->maquina;
    $headform->codigo_formulario =$request->codigo_formulario;
    $headform->producto_tamaño=$request->producto_tamaño;
    $headform->hora_inicio=$request->hora_inicio;
    $headform->hora_final=$request->hora_final;
    $headform->fecha_empaque=$request->fecha_empaque;
    $headform->fecha_vencimiento=$request->fecha_vencimiento;
    $headform->lote=$request->lote;
    $headform->inspecion_filtros=$request->inspecion_filtros;
    $headform->operario=$request->operario;
    $headform->ingeniero=$request->ingeniero;
    $headform->observaciones=$request->observaciones;

    $headform->save();
}
```

En resumen los campos lote y código formulario los cuales se llenan con una función de *JS* no guardan en la base de datos el resto de datos si guardan bien.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: si claro  todo el formulario guarda bien menos los dos campos  que indique

Comment: A veces me ha pasado y al final resulta ser el disabled del input, prueba. Y sustituye tu disabled por un readonly

Comment: si funciono el reandoly  gracias  men  y por que estan disabled es para evitar que lo modifiquen  solo es para leer

Comment: De nada, entonces solo dejalos como readonly, que bueno que ya te funcionó

Comment: @JoséVásquez considera publicar tu solución, así el OP la puede marcar como aceptada y ayuda a que la pregunta no quede abierta

Comment: @BetaM ok ahorita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reemplaza la propiedad `disabled` de tus inputs y reemplazalo por un `readonly` y de esta forma el controlador recibirá los datos.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label">Lote No</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text"   name="lote" id="lote" value="lote" readonly >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <input value="cformulario" title="codigo formulario" type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo_formulario" id="cformulario" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```